# Rails view helpers and formatting very long lines in html.erb files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

Some of my html.erb files are very long. Due to multiple attributes and sometimes conditions.

For example:

```
<div class="comment-container">
  <div class="comments">
    <div class="user-info"></div>
    <span class="toggle-comments pull-right comment-activity <%= 'hidden' unless @item.comment_threads.size != @item.root_comments.size %>" data-id="<% item.id %>" data-commentid="<% comment.id %>" data-userid="<% user.id %>">
        <i class="fa fa-comment-o fa-lg"></i>
    </span>    
  </div>
</div>
```

What is the best way to format something like this? Should I use a `content_tag`? Just leave it as is?

Answer (score 1):

You can take `<%= 'hidden' unless @item.comment_threads.size != @item.root_comments.size %>` and put in on a helper method:

```
def hidden(item)
  'hidden' unless item.comment_threads.size != item.root_comments.size
end
```

Then in your view you just call your method:

```
<div class="comment-container">
  <div class="comments">
    <div class="user-info"></div>
    <span class="toggle-comments pull-right comment-activity <%= hidden(@item) %>" data-id="<%= item.id %>" data-commentid="<%= comment.id %>" data-userid="<%= user.id %>">
      <i class="fa fa-comment-o fa-lg"></i>
    </span>    
  </div>
</div>
```

You won't get rid of the whole line, but makes it cleaner.

If you still don't like that long line, you can break the attributes into different lines, something like this:

```
<div class="comment-container">
  <div class="comments">
    <div class="user-info"></div>
    <span
      class="toggle-comments pull-right comment-activity <%= hidden(@item) %>"
      data-id="<%= item.id %>"
      data-commentid="<%= comment.id %>"
      data-userid="<%= user.id %>">
      <i class="fa fa-comment-o fa-lg"></i>
    </span>    
  </div>
</div>
```

I prefer breaking the attributes in new lines, but not everybody likes it, so use the one that you are more comfortable with.